# Powershell: Match combobox

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell, ms-access-2010

Been stuck on this for days... I have a winform with a combobox that is populated with "Contexts" from  an access table, When the user selects a context I want a textbox to populate with the matching "server" from that Colum in the same table.

This is what I have so far..
Thanks for any help!,

```
$conn=New-Object -com "ADODB.Connection"
$rs = New-Object -com "ADODB.Recordset"

$conn.Open ('Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=C:\users.mdb;Persist Security Info=True;')

$rs.Open("SELECT * FROM tblContext",$conn,$adOpenStatic,$adLockOptimistic)

$rs.MoveFirst()

do {$rs.Fields.Item("Context").Value  

$Label4ComboBox.items.add($rs.Fields.Item("Context").Value)
$Label4ComboBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add($rs.Fields.Item("Context").Value);
$Label4ComboBox.AutoCompleteMode = [System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode]::SuggestAppend;
$Label4ComboBox.AutoCompleteSource = [System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource]::CustomSource;
$rs.MoveNext()

$rs.Fields.Item("Server").Value;

} until ($rs.EOF -eq $True)
```

Comment: Can you please describe what part of this is not working.  Are you getting errors when executing?  What is the behavior?

Comment: The above is working, What I am trying to do is add a textbox to show the resulting server from the context selected in $label4combobox, so something like: $textbox1 = $rs.fields.item("server").value But I am not sure how to link that result from $lable4combobox.selecteditem

Comment: So it sounds like you need to register a handler for the SelectedIndexChanged event on the combobox.  When the event occurs you need to assign the selected item to the text property of the textbox.  See documentation for [Register-ObjectEvent](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849929.aspx).

Comment: @Cobster has part of it, you need to register the event. You probably also need to do a new query against your Access DB, something like `"SELECT * FROM tblContext WHERE 'Context' = '$($Label4ComboBox.SelectedItem)'"` That may need tweaking, but it should be pretty close.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. This is the code..
    $Label4ComboBox.add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $rs.Open("SELECT * FROM tblContext WHERE Context='$($Label4ComboBox.selecteditem)';",$conn,$adOpenStatic,$adLockOptimistic)